# Creating a toggle in the Chrome extension icon to toggle on/off a javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I trying to use the `default_popup` option to create a html page which will open the extension popup, the html file when I click on my extension.

Now I have `content.js` script which I want to toggle on/off. I was thinking a button in the html popup page which will trigger the script to turn on/off.

Do I have to use the onClicked event listener to do that? First time trying to create an extension. Would love to know how would I go about doing this, thanks!

Comment: What do their DOCs say to do?

Comment: I think I can create the onClicked event in backgroud.js, but I don't know how do I incorporate with content.js to toggle it on/off.

Comment: the docs and samples show how. do show us first your attempt and whats not working.

Comment: So I have this in background.js chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  if(message.method == 'setJS')
    jsToggle = content.js;
})

now I'm not sure how to actually use `setJS` in the html to toggle it

Answer (score 0):

Content script can't be really removed/disabled via programming, however, you could set a flag in you content script and determine whether or not to execute real logic by checking the flag.

To toggle the flag, you could use [Programming injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) or [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).